# How can two versions of the Linux kernel show as being installed at the same time?

Tags: 18.04, kernel

When I use `dpkg` to list the installed Linux images on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I see two different versions installed. How can this be?

[image: screenshot]

`uname -r` reports version 5.3.0.40 as the current. Is it safe or do I need to uninstall the older version manually?

Comment: Version 5.3.0-28 is the previous (backup) version. Ubuntu always keeps two kernel versions, in case you may need to revert to the previous version.

Comment: You can have many installed, but you'll only have a single kernel running at a time (unless you include VMs that could be running a different kernel etc).  In `grub` you can select older kernels should you have problems with a new kernel change; so having multiple kernels available is really useful come problems.

Comment: dpkg describes packages on disk, you can have multiple kernel versions present on disk even though only one of them is the one running.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I assume, so, that over time the oldest version will be removed and replaced.  I'll keep a watch out.  On a related matter, when I was looking at this I came across an "unsigned kernel", which alarmed me a bit. How could that have been there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal behavior.

Your Ubuntu system will keep at least two kernels installed. Sometimes more.

New kernels occasionally have regressions for some folks, or (for a very few) won't boot at all. The ability to boot from an older kernel is a welcome feature for folks affected by these rare issues.

You can choose which kernel to use at the GRUB menu during boot. Generally, if you don't choose, GRUB will boot the newest kernel that it knows about. You can only choose at boot, you cannot switch kernels on a running system.